# What is tricomfi by estdemin?

Tags: windows

I recently installed a fresh copy of windows and looked at installed programs to find something called `tricomfi` by “estdemin” with a size of 272 KB.

The only program I have installed so far is Opera Web Browser.

Comment: Which Windows version?

Comment: @MKzero Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

When you search for tricomfi on [System Explorer](http://systemexplorer.net/file-database/file/tivesen-dll/29602492), you will find, that a `tivesen.dll` will show up.

Searching for that DLLs MD5 on [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/6aacfb1f5677105bb09e714abcd4096a11e15bfca87892197fbb1870b8089eb6/analysis/) only shows a 1/56 detection ratio with the only detection beeing "WS.Reputation.1". What that means is not defined exactly and Symantec is [very fuzzy about it](http://community.norton.com/en/forums/clarification-wsreputation1-detection):

```
WS.Reputation.1 is a detection for files that have a low reputation score based 
on analyzing data from Symantec’s community of users and therefore are likely to
be security risks. Detections of this type are based on Symantec’s 
reputation-based security technology. Because this detection is based on a 
reputation score, it does not represent a specific class of threat like adware 
or spyware, but instead applies to all threat categories. 

The reputation-based system uses "the wisdom of crowds" (Symantec’s tens of 
millions of end users) connected to cloud-based intelligence to compute a 
reputation score for an application, and in the process identify malicious 
software in an entirely new way beyond traditional signatures and 
behavior-based detection techniques.
```

So it's probably nothing bad, but could be - because you just installed your computer it's vulnerable to many attack vectors and this could be a rogue drive-by-download. You could let VirusTotal check that file again or - if you are not sure, just reinstall again. If it's still there after a fresh install, this might come from your Windows install source and you would want to download the standard ISO from Microsoft.

Comment: Hmmm I used the ISO from microsofts download servers :|

Answer (score 0):

As this [following link](http://appquantify.com/p149515-tricomfi.aspx):

> This app has a very high trust score.

for removing it:

```
MsiExec.exe /x{74f1e872-8d6f-4cc7-58d6-c60d8dfe43ed}
```

I found it even in recovery disks of windows 7, so i think this software is installed with windows.

And a non-trusted source tells it's related to windows theme.